# Duplicated code generation flags on CMAKE Cuda/ptx project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cuda

I want to compile cuda to ptx for embedding. For this I am using CMAKE 3.18.5 with visual studio 16(2019) generator, which is a requirement from the project. The problem I am having is that the target flags are duplicated `compute_75,compute_75;compute_75,sm_75` and because of that nvcc refuses to compile it to ptx.

> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
> 11.2.targets(625,9): error : More than 1 Code Generation option is specified, this is only allowed if NVCC Compilation Type is 'compile'
> or 'fatbin'.

For a minimal working example I use a code example for how to do this from a [github repo](https://github.com/robertmaynard/code-samples/tree/master/posts/cmake_ptx) which was
featured in nvidia devblog. This example works.
I change the example to require CMAKE 3.18 (from 3.8) and add

```
set_property(TARGET CudaPTX PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)
set_property(TARGET ExportPTX PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES off)
```

At line 51 (after target_include_directories) and my problem is manifested.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hi7e.png).

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How do I begin debugging something like this?
3. How can I change my code example to compile, given I require cmake 3.18 and vs2019?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to CMake generating architectures for both [real and virtual devices](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html), which is unfortunately incompatible with PTX generation.

Using the following forces using only the virtual architecture, and fixes the problem:

```
set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75-virtual)
```